# Twincat Xml file read and write stopped working

Tags: twincat

I made a custom function block which uses `FB_XmlSrvRead` and `FB_XmlSrvWrite` from the [Tc2_TcXmlDataSrv](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6421_tc3_xml_server/187110539.html&id=) library, to read and write an xml file. The functionality of the custom function blocks are tested with the [TcUnit](https://tcunit.org/) library. After moving the unit tests to a new project, only the tests which used the either a xml read or write failed, but other unit tests in the new project still worked.

The xml function blocks reported the following error:

| Error code | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1808 | ADSERR_DEVICE_SYMBOLNOTFOUND | Symbol not found. |

I tried to write different symbols, but each time it failed. I'm quite sure the symbols exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had added `{attribute 'hide'}` above the program which I used to execute the unit tests. Somehow this caused only the unit tests which needed to read or write an xml file to fail. Other unit tests were not affected.